# Rounding up all the decimals in PHP

Tags: php, rounding

Are there functions that would round up all the decimals in an integer?.For example:

```
1.2 = 2
1.7 = 2
```

Or is there a computation that I could use to round up all the decimals?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ceil()`  http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

```
<?php
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
echo ceil(9.999);  // 10
?>
```